# Границы форматированного текста (например, курсива) в диалоге: где они начинаются и где заканчиваются?

Tags: пунктуация, оформление-текста, диалог, оформление-книги, курсив

Есть, например, необходимость выделить речь по телефону *курсивом*, чтобы чётко показать, что она слышится по-особенному (из аппарата, персонаж физически рядом не присутствует). Но где тогда начинается и кончается курсив? Я бы не стал брать в курсив диалоговое тире, а также знаки (тире с запятой (, — ), которые отделяют "нормальный" текст от форматированного, насчёт точки с тире (. — ) не уверен). Также не стал бы брать в курсив слова ГГ, поскольку в понимании читателя он говорит *в телефон*, то есть ничем не отличается от того, как слышится его речь обычно; в отличие от персонажа, который находится не здесь, не от его лица ведётся повествование и речь его уже слышится *из телефона*. Но верно ли это, какие есть примеры и чем руководствоваться в таких случаях? Квадратными скобками хочу показать границы курсива. Как правильно?

— Алло, это ты, что ли?
— [*Ага, кто же ещё*], — потрескивающим из-за плохой связи голосом сказал Гена.
— И где ты?
— [*А, ну это*], — неуверенно начал он, — [*в Москве, ясное дело.*]
— Чего?
— [*Ну, в Москве.*] — Гене явно было немного неловко. — [*А я не говорил разве?*]

Особенно в последнем случае — точка перед тире ("Ну, в Москве. — ...") входит в курсив или нет?

Answer (score 3):

> При наборе курсивом или полужирным словосочетания (части предложения)
> знаки препинания, относящиеся не только к выделенным словам, набирают
> шрифтом основного начертания (например, светлым прямым), а знаки
> препинания, относящиеся только к выделенной части, — выделительным
> шрифтом. *[см. [здесь](https://myfilology.ru/168/texnicheskie-pravila-nabora/#), пункт "выделения и втяжки".]*

Я бы писал так:

— Алло, это ты, что ли?
— ***Ага, кто же ещё,*** — потрескивающим из-за плохой связи голосом сказал Гена.
— И где ты?
— ***А, ну это,*** — неуверенно начал он, — ***в Москве, ясное дело***.
— Чего?
— ***Ну, в Москве.*** — Гене явно было немного неловко. — ***А я не говорил разве?***

Comment: Хм, а почему тогда вы бы курсивом выделили запятые перед тире, а точку в конце не стали бы (последнее вообще кажется странным)?

Comment: @ShiKomarishe потому что точка в конце закрывает предложение, в котором не только курсив (поскольку вся целиком фраза, с авторскими словами внутри, — у вас записано как одно предложение). Если бы последняя часть фразы, курсивная, была отдельным предложением, точка была бы курсивная. — ***А, ну это,*** — неуверенно начал он. — ***в Москве, ясное дело.***

Comment: Тогда вы не могли бы, пожалуйста, дополнить свой ответ рассуждениями об этих нюансах с объяснениями? Чтобы всё было, как говорится, по полочкам...

Comment: @ShiKomarishe растолкованное мною в комментарии следует из правила, приведённого в ответе. Sapienti sat.

Comment: А запятые почему выделили на границе форматов?

Comment: @ShiKomarishe потому что запятая относится к выделенному тексту. Если бы выделена была только часть текста, запятая была бы обычная: "— Ага, ***кто же ещё***, — потрескивающим из-за плохой связи голосом сказал Гена". Также и при перечислении, не все элементы которого выделены, запятые всюду обычные, а не выделенные: "...даты жизни, область деятельности, слова ***сын***, ***отец***, ***старший***, ***младший*** заключают в круглые скобки".

Comment: Так, а если бы была диалоговая реплика в курсиве без доп. пояснений, точка бы была в курсиве или нет? Если диалоговое тире — нет, то и точка нет, или как? Например: " — Ну, в Москве".

Comment: @Shi Komarishe Я рассматриваю начальное тире как особый знак, который не выделяется курсивом никогда (за исключением тех случаев, когда весь кусок текста, весь диалог пишется курсивом). Иначе был бы разнобой: к примеру, в одном диалоге есть и реплики без авторских слов (то есть только курсивные), и реплики с авторскими словами (набранными обычным шрифтом); так что же, писать в первом случае курсивное тире, во втором -- обычное? Конечно нет. Поэтому: — ***Ну, в Москве.***